# How to get outlook platform like it windows, mac or owa for add in

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I want to get the platform of outlook whether it is the mac, windows 2016 or owa for my add-in. Is there any API of office which provides such details???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `Office.context.platform` property which provides the platform on which the add-in is running. Possible values are: `PC`, `OfficeOnline`, `Mac`, `iOS`, `Android`, `Universal`.

Answer (score 1):

Office.context.platform may not be implemented in older versions of Office.js. Another way to get to the information you are looking for is Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName. This would return values like: Outlook, OutlookIOS, or OutlookWebApp. In combination with Office.context.mailbox.diagnostivs.hostVersion you can figure out if its Outlook desktop 2016 or not. The hostVerison for Outlook 2016 would look like 16.xx...